# How to fire onSelectStart in React/JSX?

Tags: reactjs, html-select, jsx

I'm familiar with the usage of `selectstart` event in HTML. I'm using `onSelectStart` in JSX. I expect it connects to `onselectstart`. But, it throws a warning saying that it's unknown.

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onSelectStart`. It will be ignored.
```

Example code:

```
function Example() {
  return (
    <div className="Example">
      <h2 onSelectStart={() => console.log("Selection started")}>Click</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried this with `react/react-dom@16.8.4` and `react-scripts@3.0.1`.
[image: Edit loving-proskuriakova-ute7j]

Is there an alternative for `onSelectStart`? If yes, how to implement the same?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#selection-events not supported by react it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#selection-events not supported by react it seems. Even on MDN docs this dont seem to be standardized event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectstart_event#Specifications so I would question validity of its usage.

Here's the workaround using refs:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-wave-sotun

```
    ref={el => {
      el &&
        el.addEventListener("selectstart", () => {
          console.log("Selection started");
        });
    }}
```

Just dont forget to remove Event listener on unmount of component.